# Adding and referencing an additional assembly in sandboxed solution

Tags: web-part, solution-package, sandbox-solution, assembly-references

I'm writing a feature to my sandboxed web part with an event receiver that would parse a html website and add the results to a sharepoint list.

The thing is I'll need to use the HTML Agility Pack and I'm not quite sure how to add it - I've located the package options, clicked "advanced" and added the assembly .dll file manually from my HDD with the deployment target set to Web Application. Now the problem is how do I reference it in my code? Also, if the same assembly is going to be used in more features in the same solutions, shouldnt I use a different approach of adding it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the solution was to deploy the assembly to GAC instead of Web Application.